# Computed @each property isn't updated

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember 2.1.0
I have 2 models - testGroup

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
tag: DS.attr('string'),
crvs: DS.hasMany('crv'),
skus: DS.hasMany('sku'),
isSKU: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: true})
});
```

and crv.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    tag: DS.attr('string'),
    ctr: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 10}),
    convs: DS.attr('number', {defaultValue: 10}),
    testGroup: DS.belongsTo('testGroup')
});
```

And in component template I show all items from testGroup.crvs with ability to change ctr/convs.

```
{{#each model.crvs as |crv|}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{crv.tag}}</td>
        <td>{{input value=crv.ctr}}</td>
        <td>{{input value=crv.convs}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

And at the end I want tot show total:

```
<div>Phases: {{total}}%</div>
```

For this issue I created a computed property in my component:

```
total: Ember.computed('model.crvs.@each.convs', function() {
    var crvs = this.get('model').get('crvs');
    if (crvs) {
        var tmp = 0;
        crvs.forEach(function(crv) {
            tmp += parseFloat(crv.get('convs'));
        });
        return tmp;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}),
```

It shows right value when page is rendered but when I change values in crvs collection the computed property isn't changed. I can see new value in ember console.

What's wrong with my property?

**Update**
I found strange behaviour. CRVs collection comes with test group from server:

```
{
            'testGroup': {
                'id': 12,
                'tag': 'foo',
                'crvs': [1, 2]
            },
            'crvs': [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    tag: 'crv1234',
                    ctr: 10,
                    convs: 6,
                    testGroup: 12,
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    tag: 'crv1235',
                    ctr: 10,
                    convs: 7,
                    testGroup: 12,
                }
            ]
        }
```

And for this collection computed property doesn't work. But if I change to model.skus collection which is added by user in UI like this:

```
var sku = this.get('targetObject.store').createRecord('sku', {
                catalogName: this.get('catalog').displayName,
                testGroup: this.get('model'),
                id: this.get('sku').sku,
                value: this.get('skuValue')
            });
            this.get('model').get('skus').pushObject(sku);
```

Then computed property works fine for such item.
So it's very strange for me such behaviour.

Comment: What do you mean by ` I can see new value in ember console.`? You can see what new value in the console? And how is it getting there?

Comment: I mean Ember plugin for Chrome. Where you can see model and its values. Values in CRV model are changed but computed property is fired only once  on page render and no more :(

Comment: Hmm, I don't see anything obviously wrong. Are you sure the computed property isn't running again? Have you tried placing a breakpoint in it?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. I put console.log inside it and it works only once :(

Comment: The only thing I can see (potentially) wrong in the code you gave us is that your attribute is a number and the `input` is likely setting it to a string value. I can't see how that would make a difference, but I don't see anything else. What happens if you manually change the value in the console by using `crv.set()` (instead of typing in the input box)?

Comment: Nothing :( If I change convs value in ember console than this value is updated in input field but computed property hasn't been fired still.

Comment: OK, that stinks. Can you post your `testGroup` model as well? Also where is your `total` computed property located? Is that in a controller or a component? Also, is this code *exactly* what you have in your project? Copy-pasted directly and not re-typed?

Comment: I updated original question to add Test Group model. All things are in component. And yes - it's exactly original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I had the same problem. There is a [bug with Ember 2.1/2.2](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12475) that breaks computed properties of relationships that use @each.

There is a workaround: use `content.@each` instead of `@each`

```
total: Ember.computed('model.crvs.content.@each.convs', function() {
    var crvs = this.get('model').get('crvs');
    if (crvs) {
        var tmp = 0;
        crvs.forEach(function(crv) {
            tmp += parseFloat(crv.get('convs'));
        });
        return tmp;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}),
```

reference answer by Pedro Rio: [Model Computed Property not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058202/model-computed-property-not-updating)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Use `[]` instead of '@each'

```
total: Ember.computed('model.crvs.[].convs', function() {
    var crvs = this.get('model').get('crvs');
    if (crvs) {
        var tmp = 0;
        crvs.forEach(function(crv) {
            tmp += parseFloat(crv.get('convs'));
        });
        return tmp;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}),
```

Comment: [] is used when you need to be notified array is changed not property. But I tried it too and it didn't work

Comment: No, `@each` is correct. `[]` is only for when you want to observe items added to or removed from the array. `@each` is for when you want to observe a property on items in that array. http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#property__each

Answer (score 0):

You are counting the wrong property. There's only one `convs` in `crvs` but multiple `crvs` in `model`:

```
Ember.computed('model.@each.crvs.convs', function() {
```

Comment: No, from ember docs: remaining: Ember.computed('todos.@each.isDone', function() {...}

Comment: `model.@each` would mean that the model was an array.

Comment: I have model (testGroup) which has crvs array of CRV model. And CRV model has convs property

Comment: Max, what you have is right. I was just responding to Henry.

Comment: You have that in the docs because `todos` is `todos: [{object},{object},{object}]`. That's why is there `todos.@each.isDone`

Comment: So yours should be `Ember.computed('model.@each.convs', function() {` or what I've written in the answer.

Comment: Well, except if you are using `RSVP` to load more than one model in your `model`

Comment: He's iterating over `model.crvs` in his template, and he says that's working correctly. That means that his model is not an array, `crvs` is an array. It's definitely `model.crvs.@each`, not `model.@each.crvs`.