# Model Computed Property not updating

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How come the computed property student.successfulEvaluations does not update unless the page is refreshed?

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/keduco/edit?html,js,output

```
App.Student = DS.Model.extend({
  username: DS.attr('string'),
  evaluations: DS.hasMany('evaluation'),
  successfulEvaluations: Ember.computed.filter('evaluations.@each.grade', function(evaluation, index, array){
    return evaluation.get('grade') >= 10;
  })
});

App.Evaluation = DS.Model.extend({
  subject: DS.attr('string'),
  grade:   DS.attr('number'),
  student: DS.belongsTo('student')
});
```

> Ember      : 2.2.0
>   Ember Data : 2.2.1

Comment: In your `jsbin` is working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in EmberJS 2.1/2.2 regarding [@each computed properties](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/12475). There's a workaround that's to use `content.@each` instead of just `@each` (See the issue for details)

```
successfulEvaluations: Ember.computed.filter('evaluations.content.@each.grade', function(evaluation, index, array){
   return evaluation.get('grade') >= 10;
})
```